# completion block with parameters

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I have written a method with completion block in nsobject class and call this method from uiviewcontroller, its working perfectly but how do I pass a nsstring parameter in this method ,following is my pice of code.

```
-(void)testingFunction:(void(^)(NSMutableArray* result))handler{
    NSMutableArray *dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlstring]];
    NSString *authStr = @"";
    NSData *authData = [authStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Basic %@",[authData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0]];
    [request setValue:authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

    //create the task
    NSURLSessionDataTask* task = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
    [dataArray addObject:[[json objectForKey:@"query"] objectForKey:@"geosearch"]];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        handler(dataArray) ;
      });
    }];
    [task resume];
}
```

and call this method from my uiviewcontroller

```
[[AllFunction sharedInstance] testingFunction:^(NSMutableArray* testResult){
    [somearray addObject:testResult];
    NSLog(@"Result was %@", somearray);
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}];
```

Comment: But you are already passing one parameter, so what is difficult about passing another?

Comment: do you want to pass a `NSString*` to `testingFunction` or to the block ??

Comment: Yes I want to pass NSString to the testingFunction

Comment: @trojanfoe I am trying this ,its gives me error. 
-(void)testingFunction:(void(^)(NSMutableArray* result))handler:(NSString*)urlstring

Comment: @Anirban I just posted an answer. Haven't you forgotten something before **:(NSString*)urlstring** ?? :)

Comment: @kimimsc I want to pass this (NSString*)urlstring  from my viewcontroller

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to pass a `NSString*` to the method:

```
-(void)testingFunction:(void(^)(NSMutableArray* result))handler andString:(NSString*) yourString;
```

Or if you want to pass a `NSString*` to the completion block:

```
-(void)testingFunction:(void(^)(NSMutableArray* result, NSString* yourString))handler;
```

**Edit:**

You can call the method like this:

```
NSString* yourString = @"Some Text";
testingFunction:^(NSMutableArray* result) {
    //Do whatever you want here
} andString:yourString;
```

Go read this: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/objective_c/objective_c_functions.htm

**EDIT2:**

As *trojanfoe* said, if your string is supposed to be an url you should use `NSURL` instead of `NSString`

Comment: Thank you kimimsc 1st one is I wanted but can you please explain how do I call this method ? it will be really helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much its work , Sorry I dont have the reputation to give you   vote :(

Answer (score 0):

As this "string" is really a URL, pass an `NSURL` instance instead:

```
-(void)testingFunction:(void(^)(NSMutableArray* result))handler
               withURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    NSMutableArray *dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    ....
}
```

However I am unsure why your question is entitled "completion block with parameters" as this question relates to an ordinary method.